# How to create or setup private app store for iPhone/iPad applications

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, appstore-approval

Team,

I would like to know how to set up appstore for its enterprise program, with only iOS applications. To be more clear on my question, I run a business and I have applications created for my business which will be used only by customers to whom I give privileges. I don't want to put these business apps into apple's app store, where anyone can browse and install the application.

Is it possible to maintain a store for my business alone where only those who I provide access to, can be able to browse and install the applications?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/), although it doesn't fit your description exactly.

Comment: Nope - enterprise program is for distributing apps within your own enterprise. One thing you're not supposed to do is install apps on devices your enterprise does not own. What shatthi wants to do isn't currently possible.

Comment: @AdamEberbach Actually... it's sort of supported now. If the company you're selling to has an Enterprise License, you can sell in the private B2B app store to only companies that you select in iTunes Connect. Nobody else will see your apps and the companies still purchase the app based on whatever licensing you set.

Comment: The B2B store is a different thing again - it is not part of the developer enterprise program. First, it is U.S. only. Second it is to business only - not to individual customers of your own business. The buyer must be enrolled in the program with a DUNS number.

Comment: Actually, the enterprise doesn't have to own the devices.  The applications just have to installed on devices used by the employees of said enterprise.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.
Thats what companies with products like Afaria and Appearean to name a few do.

Comment: Apperian does exactly this. I work there and I do this all day every day, delivering iOS / Android / Blackberry / Windows Phone apps through private enterprise app stores. No need for the official app stores

Answer (score 3):

In a word: no.  You can't deliver apps publicly (outside your own enterprise) to non-jailbroken phones, except via the app-store.

Comment: One exception: you can deliver test applications to up to 100 devices, if you have a developer account.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) comes close to what you think?

The target device(s) get a link with which they get to your TestFlight site. When they visit it the first time, they'll have to register their device via a profile and then get a testflight app from which they can download your app as often as they want.

Con: No payment possible.

cheers

Finn

Answer (score 3):

Looking for the same thing and found this https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/. Its for Business 2 business distriubtion

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Deployment of iOS apps to any non-employee's stock OS devices, on 100 or more devices, or for a longer duration than past your Ad Hoc Distribution certificate expiration date, requires submitting your App to the iOS App store, and distributing it from there if approved by Apple.  This is true for all individual, company or enterprise developers.

For employees of D&B rated corporations, or for fewer than 100 devices for only some number of months, there are other options.